# dealing with includes and using headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have "Hello World" code that uses function fhi from another hi.cpp file that has it's header.

Correct my if my understanding is wrong according following:

I can do include cpp file like  `#include "c:\c\hi.cpp"` instead of using header without any problems except that fact that it looks more readable in header file.

If I include header like sample in my main program `hi.h`, must `hi.h` include `hi.cpp`, or it is done automatically according the same file name `hi`. I'm wondering how compiler knows where is function `fhi` body.

Is it possible to have different names for header and cpp files?

Programm:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "c:\c\hi.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
fhi(1);
return 0;
}
```

hi.h

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <iostream>

 int var;
 int  fhi(int f);
```

hi.cpp

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <iostream>

 int  fhi(int f)
 {
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> must hi.h include hi.cpp

No. `hi.h` contains only declarations, that can be other by other .cpp files.

> I'm wondering how compiler knows where is function fhi body.

It doesn't. You need to compile all *.cpp files into the object files. In your case, you will have two object files: `program.o` and `hi.o`. The linker can now take these two object files, and spit out the executable. References to other functions(in this case the actual definition of fhi(..)) is resolved in this stage.

Also why are you using absolute paths in #includes? It will break when you move the "c" directory around.

Comment: hi.c and hi.cpp are in different directory than project. I told compiler where header resists by `#include "c:\c\hi.h"`. How to tell compiler where is hi.cpp? You are right about absolute path.

Comment: Use relative paths. Something like `#include "../otherDir/otherFile.h"

Comment: `"../otherDir/otherFile.h"`  yes, this will tell compiler where is .h. But how compiler will know where is .cpp ? In my case cpp is in `../otherDir/`

Comment: @user1501700 Did you read my answer? You need to compile all cpps **separately** (into object files) thats how it knows. Here's how it is: a) folder1/folder2/abc.cpp compiles to folder1/folder2abc.o b) ./def.cpp compiles to ./def.o c) linker's inputs are  folder1/folder2/abc.cpp and ./def.o and output is your executable. (This eg assumes you provide appropriate paths)

Comment: It is clear with object files, but I'm not dealing with them. Visual Studio c++ does everything for me. And everything works fine. My question is how visual studio knows that body of the function defined in header is in the same "another" directory where header exist. I did't told to c++ about hi.cpp nothing. I suppose that it will look for cpp file in the same name and same location like header file - is that true?

Comment: I do not know about VC++, I work with an editor and a console. IMO, you should have already added the cpp to the project or something. No IDE will auto-add cpp files without user wanting it. Open a new project, have one of your cpp files, and build it. You should get many `undefined reference error`s in the linking stage.

Answer (score 2):

What normally happens is that the build system compiles the `.cpp` files into object files, that then are used to build the main executable. The means to tell this to the build system vary greatly.

One important point is that your `hi.cpp` **must** include `hi.h`. You should also put an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in `hi.h`, to make it safe to be included more than once in a translation unit.

Comment: why `hi.cpp must include hi.h`? It works without this inclusion either .

Comment: @user1501700 in your case, it doesn't matter, but in general, one separates *declaration* and *definition*. The *definitions* of functions or class member functions may need to know of other declarations, which they get from the header.

Answer (score 2):

> I can do include cpp file like #include "c:\c\hi.cpp" instead of using
>   header without any problems except that fact that it looks more
>   readable in header file.

yes, you can do so but it is not recommended, one of the problems is encapsulation; you are not hiding implementation details. readability as you mention is also a concern, a header is easier to read since it clearly shows what methods are public.

> If I include header like sample in my main program hi.h, must hi.h
>   include hi.cpp, or it is done automatically according the same file
>   name hi. I'm wondering how compiler knows where is function fhi body.

the header needs to be explicitly included in hi.cpp and any .cpp file that use the class defined in the header.

> Is it possible to have different names for header and cpp files?

yes but it is not recommended, it makes it more difficult to find things.

as a general rule: think about that other programmers may want to look in your code so you need to structure it so that it is easy to read and understand as well as making it easier for you 2 years down the road to remember where things are.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio all CPP files included in the project will be compiled to produce OBJ files. These OBJ files will be linked together to form the EXE or DLL.

Including files are similar to pasting the contents of the file at that location. The only difference is that this pasting is done by the pre-compiler during compilation.

Finding out where a function body resides is done by the either the compiler if the function is inline or by the linker when the final binary is created.

Answer (score 2):

First, if the header file is in the same directory as the source file including it, you can use just

```
#include "hi.h"
```

In other words, you don't have to use a full path. (See e.g. the inclusion of `"stdafx.h"`.)

Second, in your header file you don't need to include other header files, unless you need types from those. In your header file you don't have anything that needed from the header files you include.

Third, you should protect header files header files from being included more than once in the same source file, this can be done with a so called [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), on in some compiler via a special directive called [`#pragma once`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once).

Fourth, in your header file you *define* a global variable `var`. This variable will then be defined in every source file you include the header file in, which will lead to errors. You need to declare the variable as `extern`:

```
extern int var;
```

Then in one source file you define the variable like you do now.

Fifth, you should never include source files in header file (with some special exceptions that you don't have to think about yet). Instead you add all source files to the project (I assume you are in MS VisualStudio) and it they will all be built and linked together automatically.

Sixth, since you seem to be using VisualC++, then you are probably using something called [precompiled headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header). This is something the compiler uses to speed up compilation. However, for this to work you have to include `"stdafx.h"` in all source files. That include actually has to be the first non-comment line in each source file.